# "Type String does not conform to protocol StringLiteralConvertible"

Tags: swift

I'm a longtime Obj-C developer but am new to Swift, like everyone else, and scratching my head at this one. I'm trying to convert an older tutorial that was written in Obj-C.

I have an "Animal" class declared like so:

```
class Animal
{
    let title: String
    let image: UIImage
    let creator: String

    init(title: String, image: UIImage, creator: String)
    {
       self.title = title
       self.image = image
       self.creator = creator
    }
}
```

And in another class, I want an array of Animal instances, which is declared as a property of that class like so:

```
let animals: [Animal]
```

And initialized (unsuccessfully) like so:

```
animals = [Animal(title: "Sleeping Cat", image: UIImage.imageNamed("ID-101.jpg") 
creator:"papaija2008"),
...
...
]
```

I am getting a build error in the first line of this array initializer, which reads just like the title of the post: "Type String does not conform to protocol StringLiteralConvertible". Can we not assign string literals to String objects? That seems impossible. What rule am I violating and how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've seen this error come up a lot, and it usually doesn't mean that something specifically string-related is wrong. Often, some parameter you're passing to a function is in some way improper. I've resolved issues like this by using a `let` with an explicit type for each relevant parameter and then passing in those variables. The compiler will generally give a more helpful error message that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `UIImage(named:)` instead of `UIImage.imageNamed()` works for me:

```
let animals: [Animal] = [Animal(title: "Sleeping Cat", image: UIImage(named: "ID-101.jpg"), creator:"papaija2008")]
```

I hope it works for you too.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I realize now that UIImage.imageNamed() is calling the old Obj-C method, which of course takes an NSString argument, so it seems that String can't implicitly convert to NSString? Of course, it makes more sense to simply use the Swift API rather than convert. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Actually the error that I see in playground is `imageNamed is unavailable: use object construction UIImage(named:)`. Btw what's important is that it solved your issue.

Comment: @ReidBelton No, `String` and `NSString` are seamlessly bridged, meaning you can pass an `NSString` where a `String` is expected, and vice versa. The problem is that Swift modifies old-style Objective-C initializers to work with its new constructor syntax. So `NSThingy.thingyWithName` in Objective-C becomes a constructor in Swift that's invoked `NSThingy(name: ...)`. You can look at the documentation for `UIImage` to see how the Swift and Objective-C invocations differ for any given method.